# How can I hide elements after exceeding a certain count JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a div with 8 children divs, but only want to display the first four. What's the easiest way to go about this with javascript or jQuery so that even if the children div's change, the last four divs will always be hidden or display: none?

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tour">Tour 1</div>
  <div class="tour">Tour 2</div>
  <div class="tour">Tour 3</div>
  <div class="tour">Tour 4</div>
  <div class="tour">Tour 5</div>
  <div class="tour">Tour 6</div>
  <div class="tour">Tour 7</div>
  <div class="tour">Tour 8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Arun P Johny*'s answer is great, but in case you needed to do this using jQuery:

```
$('.wrapper .tour:gt(3)').hide();
```

Answer (score 9):

Using css, [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child)

```
.wrapper > :nth-child(n + 5) {
    display: none;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L3Xwt/)

---

of jQuery use .slice() since it is faster than the alternate :lt

```
$('.wrapper > .tour').slice(4).hide()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L3Xwt/2/)